# Change data type of an existing column in a data extension from text to date

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

How can I change the data type of an existing column of a data extension from text to date in exact target. The values in the column are in this format `2015-09-13 00:00:00`.

Comment: You cannot change data type of an existing DataExtension columns.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Data Extension with the desired field structure and query the data into it. You will probably have to use SQL's `CONVERT()` function on the Text field in order to insert it into the new Date field.

If the field you are changing is named date_field, your SQL might start with something like this:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_field, 101) AS [date_field]
```

Answer (score 0):

We will not be able to change the Data Extension field type.  You can export the data and import it into your new data extension.  If you do not want to write a query and it's an one time job, but if it's recurring you probably can run the query in Automation Studio.