# Modify Decimal Value DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I need to modify the length value of a decimal type field in a Data Extension, but i can't do it from the UI, how can i change this value?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Try this approach answered by [gortonington](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12730/gortonington) here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187827/can-i-decrease-the-length-of-a-column-in-data-extension

Answer (score 2):

As @VishalKumarCV stated in his comment, [can i decrease the length of a column in data extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187827/can-i-decrease-the-length-of-a-column-in-data-extension) is likely your only solution.  This is because although you can change the MaxLength field (Left side of the Length) the Scale property (right side of Length - after the comma) is not editable.

This means that both values are not editable in the UI, and only the MaxLength property is editable via API. So to change the Scale, you will need to recreate the field or recreate the DE with the new field length and then import your data into that new field/de.

Example of Scale Property results in Describe request to DataExtensionField SOAP Object:

```xml
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Scale</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
```

You will notice `IsUpdatable` is false, meaning you can only create/retrieve. Not update.

*(Weird thing about this is that MaxLength is listed as not updatable either, but it is... I did try doing Scale as MaxLength worked, but no success. Might be that only some fieldtypes MaxLength can change, but others it cannot so for overall answer it was just listed as not updatable.)*

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the Quickly answer!! Very useful :)